# White space at top of custom wordpress theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes

There's this ridiculous 16px whitespace/margin at the top of the theme I'm building, between the header and admin bar. Firebug shows no margin nor padding, and I've tested it with !important to make sure. I saw someone say it was due to the encoding the header file was saved with, so I re-saved as UTF-8 (no BOM) and no change.

It shows up in Firefox, Safari & Chrome.

Any ideas what it is and how to remove it?

Top is admin bar, then the mysterious white space, then header.

[image: Top is admin bar, bottom is header]

Answer (score 0):

Not Sure if this is of any help but I found this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-white-space-on-top-of-template

Comment: Have seen that, and unfortunately doesn't help. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Found a hidden margin to  in the minimzed file that I missed. Fixed!